# Eigenfunctions of quantum systems being uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to show that eigenfunctions of quantum systems tend to $0$ as $x\to \pm\infty$.

Working in the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ even though all functions are normalisable, they may not go to $0$ as $x\to \pm\infty$ - certain nasty examples of functions can be formulated.

I believe it is the case that all uniformly continuous functions in $L^2$ **do** tend to $0$ as $x\to \infty$, so I need a proof that all eigenfunctions are uniformly continuous, or failing that, a proof that the eigenfunctions of a quantum system do indeed go to $0$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

Comment: Are you looking at $Hf=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f+V(x)f$ or something more general? If so, are there assumptions on the behavior of $V$ at $\infty$?

Comment: I assume you deleted your old question?

Comment: If you are considering bound state problems, then the eigenfunctions $\psi $ are those that satisfy Schrodinger with the condition that $\psi (x)\to 0 $ as $x\to \pm \infty$. i.e., it is a requirement that the eigenfunctions vanish at infinity. You can convince yourself of this if you try to solve the harmonic oscillator problem without it. If you are considering unbound states then itis not even possible to impose the condition that the eigenfunctions vanish at infinity. For a free particle in one dimension, the solution is $\psi(x)=ae^{ix}+be^{-ix}$,which is not even $L^{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a $1d$ Schrodinger problem to be well-posed, it is necessary that the Hamiltonian
$$
               Hf = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f+Vf
$$
be essentially selfadjoint on the domain $\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of compactly-supported infinitely-differentiable functions. (If this were not true, then there would be a non-trivial boundary condition at $\infty$, and conditions at $\infty$ make no sense because they cannot be imposed, and that would result in an ill-posed physical problem.) For real functions $f\in\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
        \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(Hf)fdx=\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f')^2dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Vf^2dx.
$$
If $V$ is uniformly bounded below by some constant $C$, then $2|ab| \le a^2+b^2$ holds for all real numbers $a$ and $b$ and gives
$$
      \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f')^2dx \le -C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^2dx+2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{|C|+1}}|Hf|\right)\left(\sqrt{|C|+1}|f|\right)dx \\
  \le -C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^2dx+\frac{1}{4(|C|+1)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(Hf)^2dx+(|C|+1)\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f^2dx \\
  \le (2|C|+1)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^2dx+\frac{1}{4(|C|+1)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(Hf)^2dx.
$$
Because $H$ is essentially selfadjoint, the above remains true for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(H)$, which then forces $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for all $f\in \mathcal{D}(H)$. Hence, $f'f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for $f\in\mathcal{D}(H)$, which gives the existence of the following limits:
$$
       \lim_{r\rightarrow\pm\infty}2\int_{0}^{r}f(r)f'(r)dr = \lim_{r\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(r)^2dr.
$$
If either limit were non-zero, that would contradict the absolute integrability of $ff'$. Therefore,
$$
          \lim_{r\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(r)=0,\;\;\; f\in\mathcal{D}(H).
$$
In particular this must hold for any $f\in\mathcal{D}(H)$ for which $Hf=\lambda f$. So normalizable eigenfunctions of $H$ must vanish at $\pm\infty$ if, for example, the potential is semibounded below. I suspect this can relaxed somewhat, but it's a beginning.

Comment: Thank you! All looks good to me and I appreciate your rigorousness there.

Comment: The only thing I would have a question about is the step where you cancelled the two integrals of $f^2$ with the $C$ coefficients. You've got a $-C$ and a $|C|$, and the only way I can see these cancelling is if $C\geq 0$, and they wouldn't cancel if $C$ were negative.

Comment: @CharleyScotford : Thank you for the feedback. And thank you for pointing out my mishandling of $C$, which I've now changed.

Comment: Good stuff as always! This was pretty enlightening. I assume that time dependence follows similar reasoning? At least in the case of time independent potentials?

Comment: @CameronWilliams : Thank you. If $H_t$ corresponds to $V(t,x)$, then normalizable eigenfunctions for a fixed $t$ would follow the same argument.